# Is it possible to let software under /opt to use configuration file under /opt filstly?

Tags: linux, configuration

We know in Linux there is `/opt` directory.
we can install a whole software under it.

but how about a software's configure file?

I compile `varnish` and installed it into `/opt/varnish`, but `/opt/varnish`, I did not find `etc` directory.

whether it will go to `/etc` directory search the configuration file?
Can I mkdir `/opt/varnish/etc` and let the varnish search it firstly?

---

I use `./configure --prefix=/opt/varnish` configure it.

Comment: How exactly did you compile the software and install it into `/opt`? The result you're after is exactly what you get when you `./configure --prefix=/opt/varnish` if the software uses autotools, for example.